# How does Now in Android keep scroll position when changing tabs?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

When switching tabs in the Now in Android example app, the tabs will keep their scroll position intact. In our own app structured the same way with the same scroll state calls the scroll position will get reset.

I thought data from rememberSaveable would get lost when a composable leaves composition, but for Now in Android app this does not seem to be the case?

Comment: Now in Android also seems to keep the view models alive between tab switches, which our app does not, the view models get created every time a tab is visited. I see no special scoping in the Now in Android code.

Answer (score 0):

Found the difference -- we had nested `navigation` elements in our graphs for the tabs. Removing these solves the issue

As per the docs for hiltViewModel

> Returns an existing ViewModel or creates a
> new one scoped to the current navigation graph present on the {@link
> NavController} back stack

I guess the rememberSaveable thing is somehow scoped here as well?